# libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file. Have libreadline-7 and dev

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

Im getting the error below while trying to run vtysh for some network simulations

```
vtysh: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Currently I have libreadline-dev and libreadline-7 installed, and made a symlink that points to libreadline.so.7 at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 but to no avail. I'm assuming it might be looking for a different path, but I'm not sure how to approach troubleshooting problems like these.

---

No such luck with the suggestions below. After compiling readline6.3 from the source code as suggested below, my output from `ldconfig -v | grep readline` is:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
    libreadline.so.6 -> libreadline.so.6.3
    libreadline.so.7 -> libreadline.so.7.0
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libguilereadline-v-18.so.18 -> libguilereadline-v-18.so.18.0.0
/home/gdc/Desktop/readline-6.3:
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib32/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
```

Comment: You can download `libreadline6` http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb and install the package with `sudo apt install Downloads/libreadline6_6.3-8+b3_amd64.deb`

Comment: @KnudLarsen It isn't a good idea to get into the habit of installing packages that aren't compatible with the system. Sometimes, you'll be alright but it only takes one time to land in dependency hell.

Comment: The Ubuntu `libreadline6` version is also available http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/readline6/libreadline6_6.3-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb .... and is equally compatible ....... and no conflicts with later versions.

Comment: Recompile vtysh so that it is linked against libreadline7 (you have the -dev package for that installed) - this may require downloading the latest version of the vtysh source (or, at least, a version from around 2018 for a version compatible with libreadline7).  Alternatively, if your `vtysh` binary came from quagga (it is included with `quagga-core` package on debian and ubuntu - neither seem to have a standalone vtysh package), then just upgrade quagga.

Comment: BTW, some important information is missing from your question.  We can't give you more than generic hints without knowing:  what version of vtysh you have, where/how you installed it (package? self-compiled?), and what distro and version you're running.

Answer (score 0):

As creating a symlink didn't work, your only other option is to compile the code from source and add it to your environment. You can get the source code for `readline-6.3` here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/

After you've compiled it, create a file the file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64_readline-gnu.conf and input the line `/path/to/readline/lib` depending on where you compiled it. Afterwards, run the command:

```
ldconfig -v | grep readline
```

You'll see that `libreadline.so.6` is in your environment and `vtysh` will run with no issues.

Comment: No such luck. below is my output from `ldconfig -v | grep readline` can be seen in my edit

Comment: I'm looking at an older 16.04 machine that is working and it looks like it might be looking for a libreadline.so.6 in /lib32/ rather than /lib/ does this seem like it makes any sense?